# How do I get a value from a string in Ruby using Regex?

Tags: ruby, string

How I do get one part of string using Ruby? I want to get the value `image/jpeg` from this string:

```
"Content-Disposition: form-data; name='arquivo'; filename='the_last_in_line.jpg' Content-Type: image/jpeg"
```

Comment: That string is illegal. You can't have a double-quoted string containing double-quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What have you tried? You can use regular expression for such tasks:

```
str='Content-Disposition: form-data; name="arquivo"; filename="the_last_in_line.jpg" Content-Type: image/jpeg'
str[/Content-Type:\s*(\S*)/,1] # => "image/jpeg"
```